# Rails dynamically add handler for after_commit on another model's instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two models:

`User` and `Upload`.

A user uploads an avatar via an /uploads api endpoint which sends back an upload id once complete.

The image then gets attached to the user instance by sending a the upload id via `avatar_upload_id` to another api endpoint: `PATCH /users/:id`

The user model has an `avatar_upload_id=` method which looks like this:

```
def avatar_upload_id=(upload_id)
  begin
    Upload.attach(upload_id, self, :avatar)
  rescue Upload::FileNotFound
    errors.add(:avatar, :missing)
  end
end
```

---

```
class Upload
  ...
  def self.attach(id, instance, attachment_name)
    if upload = Upload.find(id)
      # add listener for after_commit on instance here so we know to remove the file atomatically

      upload.open do |file|
        instance.send("#{attachment_name}=", file)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I want the upload to be removed `after_commit` because it's stored on the server just until Paperclip copies it over to S3. After that I don't need it on the server anymore so I want the Upload.attach method to add a handler which listens for when the model is committed and then removes the local file.

I don't want to cleanup the local file in my user model because then I'd be repeating myself in other models which also behave similarly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to add a callback handler at runtime via the following:

```
class << instance
  after_commit do
    upload.delete!
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach would be to call the instance class method:

```rb
instance.class.after_commit { upload.delete! }
```